# about ngnix / htaccess config

Tags: .htaccess, url, query-string

i need to get querystring end of the path
all path define a url variable

[www.root.com/path1/path2/path3/page?id=15&do=post](http://www.root.com/path1/path2/path3/page?id=15&do=post)

i can get all path to variable but i can not get the querystring  "id" and "do"

my config is here

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: Nginx doesn't use `.htaccess` files, those are an Apache thing.  So if you are using nginx, you shouldn't be trying to use `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect your implementation with the `QSA` flag to work as expected. A simple [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=4f77611a-f63e-4867-a9fa-6117f0c748ba) confirms that (see "The new url ..." at the bottom). So you might want to investigate why your tests came out different...

However there are alternatives, you could also actively capture the query string. The documentation of the apache rewrite module clearly says that you need a `RewriteCond` to capture the query string of a requested URL.

This might point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&do=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&id=%1&do=%2 [L]
```

That would be a simplified version:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&do=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}&id=%1&do=%2 [L]
```

Or even simpler, if that is enough for you, since you don't have to capture the query string at all:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks it work `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, it worked fine for htacess. I wrote it as follows for nginx and it works, but the page loads twice. When I remove the config below, it returns to normal.

Note: I was able to understand that the page was loaded twice by creating a file with a random name.

===nginx config ===

```
  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?qs=$request_uri&$query_string$is_args$args;
 }
```